# Control of a resonant capacitor

Tags: switches, communication, resonance

I am working on a data transmission system. For the data signal to be fully amplified, I want the circuit to resonate. I would like the signal to be already fully amplified across the inductors and avoid the signal ringing as much as possible when the data is no longer transmitted. I have been trying to figure out what would be the best way to do this without making this circuit too complex.

Until now I added switches (as in Figure 1) so that the capacitor can discharge across the resistor to limit the ringing, but I would like to limit it even more and be left with a beautiful amplified signal with the same amplitude across the inductors.

Please let me know if I can provide any additional information on the circuit. Any help would be much appreciated.

[image: Proposd circuit.]
Figure 1. Proposed circuit.

[image: Signal across the inductors.]
Figure 2. Signal across the inductors.

Comment: if you make R2 200 Ohms, then M1 and R1 are not needed. The energy is mainly in the inductors not the capacitor. Thus your 'switch' circuit is trying to dampen the inductors. Can you tell us why you are concerned about the envelope of the signal? What do you mean by 'beautiful amplified signal'?

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I found it very useful. I would like to make the ringing time much lower because I am using this system for data modulation, therefore, the ringing affects my data speed and the data reading precision in my demodulation circuit.

Comment: Lower the Q of your circuit and/or time the mosfet on at zero crossing to ‘quench’ the energy.